# Is Amazon serverless really serverless? Where to store API keys

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, serverless

I'm new to this amazon serverless architecture.

I have created a static website and hosted on netlify. There is no authentication on the site, so everything is publicly accessible (no login/password). When the user clicks a button, I call a lambda function to download a file from an S3 bucket.
This is all working fine.

But now, help me to understand, if this architecture is 'serverless' , where do I store the api key to call the lambda function?
I mean, I'm absolutely not storing the api keys on the client side, as then anyone could have access the api key and then defeat the purpose of the api key.

I don't want either make the lambda function publicly accesible, as anyone could just use the browser developer tools to get the address to call the lambda function and create a small program to call the lambda function a million times, and I would be paying for that.....

In classic applications we used to store the keys on the server side, so they are not accessible by anyone. Should I then buy a server only to store my api keys? So then, serverless, is not really serverless!!!

Please share your thoughts

Comment: But you don't mind if your lambda is called million times through your website?

Comment: "Serverless" is a marketing term with no real meaning. Don't worry, everything is fine.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by going "serverless"? Exposing the lambda function publicly (via API Gateway) is no different from exposing a traditional web-app, except that you'll be charged for each invocation.

Comment: Then what's the purpose of the Api key? I thought it was to allow only certain clients to access the API. In that case, I want the lambda function to be called ONLY from my website. If the lambda function needs to be publicly available to anyone, then the fact that I'm paying for each invocation is exactly what scares me. I guess the only solution to this would be to set a usage plan and restrict number of invocations/month, to avoid 'evil scripts'

Comment: It all depends on what you want to achieve. For example, if you want to restrict access to the function to a limited number of users, use API keys but give each user their own key and charge them for usage (I know a person who does just this, and loves Lambda for the ability to easily do that). If you want a publicly-accessible website, you're probably better off using a traditional server-based web-app.

Comment: Instead of direct firing Lambda, place `API Gateway` in front and do all the necessary authentication to allow/block lambda firing

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) - this will allow you to create a web-accessible endpoint for your Lambda function that you can secure with a custom authorizer (e.g. to require a valid JWT to be passed by an authorized user).

You can also use API Gateway Proxy Integration to pass things like path parameters or query string parameters from the web request into your Lambda function.